# Objective-C - wrap attribute value with commas in NSPredicate CONTAINS

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

Here is the situation. I have some Core Data data and I want to get the data where the value of an attribute wrapped with two commas contains another string.

This is my current code:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"type CONTAINS %@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@",%@,",typeBar]];
```

Simply put, this is what I want to achieve:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@",type, CONTAINS %@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@",%@,",typeBar]];
```

With the commas around the 'type'. But obviously when I do it like this, it doesn't recognise the attribute anymore. I have tried ,'type', but that doesn't work either.

I have tried this:

```
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@",%K, CONTAINS %@", @"type", [NSString stringWithFormat:@",%@,",typeBar]];
```

But I get a: `'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse the format string ",%K, CONTAINS %@"'`

I hope the question was clear enough.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is what you really want a predicate to search for `typeBar` at the beginning, middle, or end of a list of comma separated values?

Comment: Exactly @pbasdf ! How can I do that?

Comment: It is possible, if a trifle messy, to get one query that will do that: in essence the predicate would look like "type BEGINSWITH %@ OR type CONTAINS %@ OR type ENDSWITH %@".  You would have to create (using stringWithFormat) the values to substitute in each case (i.e. with commas at the end, both ends, and start).  You might feel it's easier to stick to Wain's option 1 below!

Comment: Ah, that's great. It's what I was looking for. But as you said Wain's solution makes it easier on the eye...Thanks a lot though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that. What you're trying is attempting to change the key to be queried to something invalid, hence the parse error.

You can't really do what you want to if you just store a plain type. Presumably your type may be a string list of things?

So, you need to rethink your approach, there are a number of options depending on what your underlying problem is:

1. Store the text for `type` with commas at the beginning and end (as well as between items)
2. Don't use a string, use some other entity (if you have a list of items)
3. Predicate on the plain type, without the commas, and then filter the results in more detail once you have the items out of Core Data (where predicates are restrictive compared to 'full' code access to the strings)

Comment: I think solution number one is the easiest in this case. Thanks for your precious help.